# DELETING any record in any table in the database if feildx=123

Tags: php, mysql

is there a mysql statemnet that goes through every table in a data base and says if applicationid =123 or schoolid=123 or familyid = 123 DELETE THE WHOLE record? i need to write a php script that will do this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/511361/how-do-i-use-on-delete-cascade-in-mysql

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT COLUMN_NAME SEPARATOR ',') AS columns 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'yourdatabasename' 
AND COLUMN_NAME IN ('applicationid', 'schoolid', 'familyid')
GROUP BY TABLE_NAME
```

The result will be an array of each table, and the columns that it has (only from the set of `applicationid, schoolid, familyid) as a comma separated field.

```
foreach ($results as $result) {
    $cols = explode(',', $result['columns']);
    foreach ($cols as &$col) {
        $col .= ' = 123';
    }
    $sql = 'DELETE FROM '. $result['TABLE_NAME'].
        ' WHERE ' . implode(' OR ', $cols);
}
```

That'll generate a query for each table like:

```
DELETE FROM table1 WHERE applicationid = 123 OR schoolid = 123
```

And it will only include the fields within the tables...

Answer (score 1):

THere's no such single statement.
You could fetch a list of table names from information_schema database, and then use stored procedure or external script to loop through it and delete these rows.

Here's reference about information_schema tables.
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-schema.html

Answer (score 0):

First use `SHOW TABLES` to get list of tables then loop through tables list and use `DELETE FROM tablename WHERE field=?`

**IMPORTANT: You should have privileges to use SHOW TABLES**

Answer (score 0):

how is

```
$showtablequery = "
SHOW TABLES
FROM
[database]
";
```

$x='0'; 
$showtablequery_result  = mysql_query($showtablequery);
while($r = mysql_fetch_array($showtablequery_result))
{
    $query="DELETE FROM $r[$x]
WHERE applicationid = 123 OR schoolid = 123 OR familyid = 123";
$x++
}