# How do the SQL "IS" and "=" operators differ?

Tags: sql, sqlite, null, operators, equality

I am building some prepared statements that use parametrized values. As an example:

```
SELECT * FROM "Foo" WHERE "Bar"=@param
```

Sometimes `@param` might be `NULL`. In such cases, I want the query to return records where `Bar` is `NULL`, but the above query will not do that. I have learned that I can use the `IS` operator for this. In other words:

```
SELECT * FROM "Foo" WHERE "Bar" IS @param
```

Aside from the differing treatment of `NULL`, are there any other ways in which the above two statements will behave differently? What if `@param` is not `NULL`, but is instead, let's say, `5`? Is using the `IS` operator in that case a safe (and sane) thing to do? Is there some other approach I should be taking?

Comment: `NULL` is an unknown or unspecified value, so nothing can ever **equal** `NULL`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You want records from Foo where Bar = @param, or if @param is null, where Bar is null.  Some of the proposed solutions will give you null records with nonnull @param, which does not sound like your requirement.

```
Select * from Foo where (@param is null and Bar is null) or (Bar = @param)
```

This doesn't say whether this is Oracle or SQL Server or another RDBMS, because they each implement slightly different helper functions.  SQL's ISNULL(first, second) like NVL(first, second).  I like SQL Server's COALESCE() for the general applicability.

The IS comparison is only for null comparisons.

If you are using SQL Server and if you *really need* a different 3VL logic truth table to solve your problem (that is, if you have a specific need for "NULL=NULL" to be "true" at some point in time, and also recognize that this is deprecated and barring your reasons, not a good idea in general), within your code block you can use the directive

SET ANSI_NULLS OFF

Here's the BOL on it:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188048.aspx

Comment: I am using SQLite, and it allows me to use `IS` to compare with non-null values. Can you cite a source that says that in standard SQL the "IS" operator is only for null comparisons?

Comment: Actually, I can: in the SQL-92 standard (free on the web), IS is a boolean operator.  Both sides are be boolean, by ANSI standard.  Null is a boolean value in 3VL logic.  Search this document for "8.12 <search condition>":
http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt,

Comment: And, I should point out, any RDBMS vendor is free to implement the standard or add additional elements however they like.  So if SQLLite wants to provide a syntactic sugar, that's their business.  It's not like SQL Server or Oracle get the full standard correct themselves.

Comment: Thank you for the source. So, it sounds like there is a quite a big difference between the two operators in **standard** SQL. In **SQLite** SQL (which I am using) it sounds like the only difference is the treatment of NULL. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: Yeah, you've solved both the specific issue and defeated my ability to locate the ANSI SQL standard - you've got my upvote as well. :)

Answer (score 7):

You may be thinking about this incorrectly. If you're talking about SQL Server, for example (since that's what I have to hand), your second example will result in a syntax error. The value on the right-hand side of IS cannot be 5.

To explain, consider MSDN's explanation of these two operators in T-SQL (note that asking about "SQL" and about "SQL Server" are not necessarily the same).

[Equals (=) operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175118.aspx)

[IS NULL operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188795.aspx)

Notice something important, there. There *is no such thing as the "IS" operator* in T-SQL. There is specifically the `<expression> IS [NOT] NULL` operator, which compares a single expression to NULL.

**That's not the same thing** as the `=` operator, which compares *two* expressions to each other, and has certain behavior when one or both of the expressions happens to be NULL!

Comment: I am using SQLite and it let's me put `5` on the right hand side of `IS` and behaves as I would intuitively expect.

Comment: Can you cite a source that says that, in standard SQL, `5` can't be put on the right hand side of `IS`? Or are you saying that `IS` isn't even standard SQL?

Comment: [Source](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/511361/how-do-i-use-on-delete-cascade-in-mysql) for standard `IS NULL/IS NOT NULL` predicate (as opposed to `IS` operator). I have yet to find reference to `IS` as a standard SQL operator, though the SQLite documentation implies it *is* a standard *reserved word*.

Answer (score 6):

Edit:
*(Update from OP: This doesn't do what I If @param is 5, then I want to see only records where Bar is 5. I want to see records where Bar is NULL if, and only if, @param is NULL. I apologize if my question didn't make that clear.)*

In that case, I think you should try something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Foo WHERE Bar=@param OR (Bar IS NULL AND @param IS NULL)
```

Previous post:

Why not simply use OR ?

```
SELECT * FROM "Foo" WHERE "Bar"=@param OR "Bar" IS NULL
```

In SQL Server, you can use ISNULL:

```
SELECT * FROM "Foo" WHERE ISNULL("Bar",@param)=@param
```

Comment: Not to be a contrarian, but, while it does provide alternatives, this doesn't actually answer the OP's question, i.e. *what is the difference between the IS and = operators*...

Comment: "In such cases, I want the query to return records where Bar is NULL, but the above query will not do that." .. "Is using the IS operator in that case a safe (and sane) thing to do? Is there some other approach I should be taking?" I believe the OP is primarily interested in a safe way to achieve this. I really don't know the difference between those except that IS is meant for NULL and I think that that was the secondary question.

Comment: I do not think this is what the OP wanted; this always returns rows where `Bar IS NULL`, while the question says "Sometimes `@param` might be NULL. In such cases, I want the query to return records where `Bar is NULL`". Not the same thing.

Comment: This doesn't do what I want. If `@param` is 5, then I want to see only records where `Bar` is 5. I want to see records where `Bar` is `NULL` if, and only if, `@param` is `NULL`. I apologize if my question didn't make that clear.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know what version of SQL you are using but IS makes no sense in the context you just described. I get a syntax error if I try to use it the way you described. Why would you want to use it over = anyway? This is the common usage and the one software maintainers woudl expect to find.

Comment: I want to use it over `=` precisely because I need the query to return results where `Bar` is NULL if `@param` is NULL. The `=` operator won't do that. It doesn't result in a syntax error on the system I'm using (SQLite).

Comment: Can you cite a source that shows that my use of `IS` is a syntax error in standard SQL? (I'm using SQLite, which allows it, but maybe that's a non-standard extension).

Comment: IS only works if the value is null in standard SQL. I Have never used SQL lite, but have you tried it when you have a numeric or string value insted of null?

Answer (score 2):

What specific database are you using?

If you're doing searches based on null (or not null), using IS is the way to go.  I cannot provide a technical reason but I use this syntax all the time.

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Field IS NULL

SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Field IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: I am using SQLite. The problem is I don't know whether I will be comparing to NULL or not. I am comparing to `@param`. At runtime, `@param` will sometimes be NULL, and at other times it will be non-NULL.