# Parameterised HQL 'is null' query becomes '= null'

Tags: sql, nhibernate, hql, query-builder

I've got a query builder that builds a parameterised HQL query for doing OData filtering. When building a query against a property being `NULL`, the `where` claluse of the HQL looks like this...

```
... where $entity.Property is ?
```

...where the `?` gets replaced by a parameter who's value is `NULL`. However, when I call `session.CreateQuery(hql)` with the above query, the SQL executed is not an `is null` query, but becomes a `=@p1` query with `@p1` filled in to be NULL. This obviously doesn't do what I want.

If I make the HQL explicitly `$entity.Propery is null` then everything works fine, but I feel like I'm missing something or doing something stupid.

What is going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5424008/1486443) `IS` is not an operator.

> Notice something important, there. There is no such thing as the "IS" operator in T-SQL. There is specifically the  IS [NOT] NULL operator, which compares a single expression to NULL.

So if you want to use `IS NULL` maybe you will need to create an dynamic query, or maybe using your parameter like `? IS NULL`.

Comment: I guess in that case NHibernate should really throw an exception if you pass it a parameterised HQL query with `x IS ?` as it doesn't make sense.