# In SQL, is there a difference between "IS" and "=" when returning values in where statements?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am currently learning SQL utilizing Codecademy and am curious if there is a difference between using "IS" or "=".

In the current lesson, I wrote this code:

```
SELECT *
FROM nomnom
WHERE neighborhood IS 'Midtown'
  OR neighborhood IS 'Downtown'
  OR neighborhood IS 'Chinatown';
```

Which ran perfectly fine. I always like to look at the answer after to see if there was something I did wrong or could improve on. The answer had this code:

```
SELECT *
FROM nomnom
WHERE neighborhood = 'Midtown'
   OR neighborhood = 'Downtown'
   OR neighborhood = 'Chinatown';
```

Do IS and = function the same?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do the SQL "IS" and "=" operators differ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5423751/how-do-the-sql-is-and-operators-differ)

Comment: Equals ´=´ is an operator. 
 ´IS NULL´ is an operator and is used as part of an expression `name IS NOT NULL`
There is no such thing as `IS` in T-SQL.

Comment: @Community This question is about SQLite, though the proposed duplicate is about other DBMS. In SQLite the operators IS and IS NOT behave differently. Check the documentation and the answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All that you want to know you can find it here:

> The IS and IS NOT operators work like = and != except when one or both
>   of the operands are NULL. In this case, if both operands are NULL,
>   then the IS operator evaluates to 1 (true) and the IS NOT operator
>   evaluates to 0 (false). If one operand is NULL and the other is not,
>   then the IS operator evaluates to 0 (false) and the IS NOT operator is
>   1 (true). It is not possible for an IS or IS NOT expression to
>   evaluate to NULL. Operators IS and IS NOT have the same precedence as
>   =.

taken from: [SQL As Understood By SQLite](http://SQL%20As%20Understood%20By%20SQLite).
The important part is: *...except when one or both of the operands are NULL...* because when using `=` or `!=` (`<>`) and 1 (or both) of the operands is NULL then the result is also `NULL` and this is the difference to `IS` and `IS NOT`.

Answer (score 1):

They work the same but "IS" is a keyword in MySQL and is generally used while comparing NULL values. While comparing NULL values "=" does not work.

```
SELECT * FROM nomnom WHERE neighborhood IS NULL
```

The above statement would run perfectly fine but

```
SELECT * FROM nomnom WHERE neighborhood = NULL
```

would result in an error.

Comment: Thank you for the response. When not working with NULL values, they do function the same though? Is "=" the preferred way to handle non NULL values?

Comment: Its not about preference. Just that IS keyword has been kind of reserved for NULL values. But it looks more acceptable to use = instead of IS. In layman terms, you are right, long story short, = is more preferred.

Answer (score 0):

They are the same for these cases, but further down the line you will discover one nifty little value called NULL.

NULL is a pain because... it doesn't exist.
0 = NULL returns FALSE;
Date <> [Column] will not return lines with NULL, only those with a value that is different.
Hell, even NULL = NULL returns false. And NULL <> NULL also returns false. That is why "IS" exists. Because NULL IS NULL will return true.

So as a general rule, use = for values.
Keep "IS" for null.

```
[Column] IS NULL
```

or

```
[Column] IS NOT NULL
```

And remember to always check if your column is nullable that you need to plan for null values in your WHERE or ON clauses.

Comment: `NULL = NULL` does *not* return "false".  It evaluates to `NULL`, which `where` clauses filter out along with "false" values.