# delete primary key also deletes foreign key

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two table, with a PK of ID. If say I delete the entry for ID = 1, I want it to automatically delete the FK of ID in the other table. In other words I want so that it should also delete all entries with ID = 1 in the other table. How can I do this? I have linked the PK-FK relationship, but when I delete the entry with ID 1 in the PK table it doesn't delete the FK.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I use on delete cascade in mysql?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/511361/how-do-i-use-on-delete-cascade-in-mysql)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you're [using the InnoDB engine](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mysql/article.php/3095771/Table-types-in-MySQL-Part-2---InnoDB-tables.htm) for both tables, and add a [foreign-key constraint](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html) specifying `on delete cascade`. Your table creation SQL should look something like this:

```
create table child_table (
    parent_id int references parent_table(id) on delete cascade
) engine 'innodb';
```

where `child_table` and `parent_table` are the names of your child and parent tables.

Comment: @EquinoX Of course. Look up the `alter table` command or use a GUI frontend like HeidiSQL.

Answer (score 0):

You have to define your Foreign Key constraints as ON DELETE CASCADE.

Note: You need to use InnoDB storage engine, he default MyISAM storage engine not support foreign keys relation.

```
CREATE TABLE `table2` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
`name` int(11) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `ids` (`ids`)
CONSTRAINT `foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`ids`)
REFERENCES `table2` (`ids`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
)
```