# Deleting rows from 3 tables at once in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli, prepared-statement

## Short

My tables structure looks like that

[image]

And here is Sql statements

```
            $stmt = $this->db->prepare("DELETE FROM chapters WHERE (subject_id=? AND id = ?)") or die($this->db->error());
            $stmt->bind_param("ii", $subject_id, $node);
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt = $this->db->prepare("DELETE FROM sections WHERE (subject_id=? AND chapter_id=? )") or die($this->db->error());
            $stmt->bind_param("ii", $subject_id, $node);
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt = $this->db->prepare("DELETE FROM paragraphs WHERE (subject_id=? AND chapter_id=?)") or die($this->db->error());
            $stmt->bind_param("ii", $subject_id, $node);
            $stmt->execute();
```

So what I want to do is, to `merge` this 3 statements into one and optimize server load.

## Detailed

For ex., if I want to delete row with id=1 from `chapters` table, then also delete from 2 more tables: `sections`, `paragraphs`by 2 parameters: `$node` and `$subject_id` (Of course, If there is rows with those parameters. I mean there must be join to prevent any error).

## Question is..

Is that possible? I can't figure out, how sql statement must  look like. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have set up foreign key constraints with `ON DELETE CASCADE` then you only need to delete the parent row. MySQL will then delete the child rows automatically.

- [How do I use on delete cascade in mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/511361/how-do-i-use-on-delete-cascade-in-mysql)

Comment: @TuralTeyyuboglu: I think you have the parent-child relationship reversed. The key is often defined on a column called `sometable_id` and refers to a column `id` in `sometable`. It seems that you have it the other way around. PS: I'm not interested in offering dedicated remote support for free, sorry!

Answer (score 4):

I haven't tried it, but you could try multi-table deletes:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/delete.html#id933512

```
    DELETE chapters, sections, paragraphs
    FROM      chapters
    LEFT JOIN sections   ON   sections.subject_id = $subject_id AND   sections.chapter_id = $node
    LEFT JOIN paragraphs ON paragraphs.subject_id = $subject_id AND paragraphs.chapter_id = $node
    WHERE                     chapters.subject_id = $subject_id AND chapters.id           = $node
```

I'm not sure if using left joins is really faster than using 3 separate deletes.