# Delete join from two tables

Tags: mysql, join, sql-delete

I need to create a join that will delete the entries in two tables. The delete will happen in projects when the project_id in the table is equal to the one on the page of the php document. I need the link entries on project_course to also be deleted. This is the code I have currently.

```
$deleteSQL = sprintf("DELETE FROM projects p
INNER JOIN project_course pc
WHERE p.Project_id=%s",
                   GetSQLValueString($_GET['Project_id'], "int"));
```

Anybody know how to do this? I haven't done a join to delete before, just a normal join.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You dont have to explicitly do this with joined queries.You can use `DELETE CASCADE` in table definition. Refer [How do I use on delete cascade in mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/511361/how-do-i-use-on-delete-cascade-in-mysql)

Comment: Dont know what happened, was set to that but reset it and now working. Thanks for the help