# Delete with joined table

Tags: php, mysql, join, sql-delete

I have two table structures here:

```
employee 
(emp_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
emp_name VARCHAR(100),
emp_ic VARCHAR(20),
emp_phone VARCHAR(20),
emp_address VARCHAR(200))

employee_medical
(id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
emp_id INT,
medical_notes TEXT,
PRIMARY KEY (id),
FOREIGN KEY (emp_id) REFERENCES employee(emp_id))
```

I want to delete row from two table which is `emp_id` but When I tried the following it didn't work.

```
$query = "DELETE employee, employee_medical
FROM employee
LEFT JOIN employee ON employee.emp_id = employee_medical.emp_id
WHERE emp_id='$id'";
```

> Error : Not unique table/alias: 'employee'

How can I fix this?

Comment: Try adding employee.emp_id as shown in the query : $query = "DELETE employee, employee_medical
FROM employee
LEFT JOIN employee ON employee.emp_id = employee_medical.emp_id
WHERE employee.emp_id='$id'";

Answer (score 2):

Your query is wrong. It should not be `DELETE employee FROM employee`, but simply `DELETE FROM employee`.

Your JOIN is also incorrect as you seem to be trying to join the same 2 tables together (you join `employee` with `employee`).

Finally in your WHERE clause you should specify from which table it should check the `emp_id`. Also you do not need the single quotes around your `$id` in this case. It's a number, not a string.

```
$query = "DELETE FROM employee
LEFT JOIN employee_medical ON employee.emp_id = employee_medical.emp_id
WHERE employee.emp_id=$id";
```

Do take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10768372/delete-join-from-2-tables?rq=1) though, I believe it's in your interest. A `DELETE CASCADE` is probably what you need instead of a `JOIN`.

Answer (score 0):

My preference is to be explicit about the tables you are deleting from (as well as using table aliases).

```
DELETE e, em
    FROM employee e LEFT JOIN
         employee_medical em
         ON e.emp_id = em.emp_id
WHERE e.emp_id = $id;
```