# On delete cascade - where I have to add it

Tags: php, mysql, sql, cascade, cascading-deletes

I needed an example of cascade delete. My question is, where do I add it? In the table I create PK, or in other tables where this PK is sitting there as FK?

Can I use "alter table" to add "on delete cascade" to existing table? An example please?

@edit
MYSQL, using phpMyAdmin

@edit 2

Does it look good?

```
alter table wplaty
  drop foreign key pesel,
  add constraint pesel foreign key (pesel)
    references baza_osob(pesel) on delete cascade on update restrict;
```

My parent table = baza_osob
My child table = wplaty

PK is pesel, FK is pesel as well.

@edit3
Got error:

> #1025 - Error on rename of '.\projekt\wplaty' to '.\projekt#sql2-1300-6c' (errno: 152)

Comment: Why don't you check the manual?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I use on delete cascade in mysql?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/511361/how-do-i-use-on-delete-cascade-in-mysql)

Answer (score 4):

cascade directives go into the "child" tables, e.g.

```
create table parent (
   id int primary key
)

create table child (
   id int primary key
   parent_id int,
   foreign key (parent_id) references parent (id)
      on delete cascade
)
```

Never tried doing an alter on a foreign key to change its `on` settings, but worst case, you simply drop the existing FK and redefine it with the new `on` settings in place.

Comment: what do you think about my main post edit? Does it look good to you ?

Comment: I get an error when updating my table that #1025 - Error on rename of '... etc. It's probably that I got multiple FK from a single PK, which is right. How can I do this..? ANy idea?

Comment: usually that error comes from using the fieldname of the key, instead of the key's internal name. do a `show create table wplaty`. that'll show the internal name, which'll probably be something like `fk_.....`.

Answer (score 0):

You actually don't add the 'ON DELETE CASCADE' on a table. It's part (or not) of each Foreign Key definition.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable this option for the foreign key. If you did not add this option when you created foreign key, then you should recreate it.

```
alter table <table> drop foreign key <fk name>;

alter table <table> add constraint <fk name> foreign key (<column name>)
  references <ref tble>(<ref column) on delete cascade on update restrict;
```

In one statement:

```
alter table <table>
  drop foreign key <old fk name>,
  add constraint <new fk name> foreign key (<column name>)
    references <ref tble>(<ref column) on delete cascade on update restrict;
```

Comment: does it "destroy" my actual foreign keys?

Comment: Yes, you should drop it firstly. It will drop the foreign key, but it won't drop index that is used by foreign key.

Comment: 2 more questions: can "new foreign key name" be the same as an old one? and ref table = parent table? ref column = pk name?

Comment: I wouldn't ask and just "do it" but it says "Do you want to destroy your databse?" xD SO I am kinda scary to do some bad moves here :) Waiting for a reply :)

Comment: tried it: error:  #1025 - Error on rename of '.\projekt\wplaty' to '.\projekt\#sql2-1300-6a' (errno: 152)

Comment: even on  alter table wplaty drop foreign key pesel; i get this error.

Comment: I did some research and there is an error that I got multiple Fk from the same PK. Yep, I do. What now..? :<

Comment: Can new FK have the same name? Yes, it can. Drop old FK, and create new one. Your script raises error because you are trying to recreate FK with the same name in one ALTER TABLE statement.