# error #1025 - Error on rename of when trying to add cascade delete

Tags: php, mysql, sql, syntax-error, cascade

I got this error:

```
#1025 - Error on rename of '.\projekt\wplaty' to '.\projekt\#sql2-1300-6c' (errno: 152)
```

I did some research, and it's probably because I am changing FK in one table but his PK is used in many tables. How can I get rid of this error?

```
My PK is in table "baza_osob", name -> pesel.
My FK are in:
-"wplaty", name -> pesel.
-"skladki_aktualne", name -> pesel.
-"dluznicy", name ->pesel.
-"skladki_wyplaty", name -> pesel.
```

I am trying from help from this topic:

[On delete cascade - where I have to add it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13920078/on-delete-cascade-where-i-have-to-add-it)

Anyone knowhow can I do this? I am using MySQL in phpMyAdmin.

@edit
Comand that "triggers" error:

```
alter table wplaty drop foreign key pesel;
```

Comment: Can you post a command that triggers the error?

Comment: it's in the other topic I linked, but ok, I edited this post.

Comment: Btw, english column names would be nice to understand the problem... pesel points to table baza_osob? If yes to which column of that table? (If yes) Can you post the output of `DESCRIBE TABLE basa_osob` ?

Comment: I already made it myself, sorry for trouble. I changed names in FK and it worked.