# MySQL Nested FOR EACH in a single trigger instead of multiple triggers

Tags: mysql, triggers

Lets say I have 3 tables:

1. meals
2. courses
3. ingredients

Where `meals` have several `courses` and `courses` have several `ingredients`.

Right now if I delete a meal, there is a trigger to delete every `courses` linked to that meal, and a second trigger that will delete every `ingredients` linked to each course.

Is there a way to do this in a single trigger with say a FOR EACH inside a FOR EACH? Surely there is a way, I'm just not good enough with triggers. I searched for "nested triggers", "nested for each", maybe I'm looking at the wrong thing.

Please don't tell me I should not delete a course after deleting a meal as it might be used for another meal, same with ingredients. This is only a simplified example of what I'm really doing.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to use a foreign_key `CONSTRAINT` with `ON DELETE CASCADE` for both tables, but it will depend if you are using InnoDB or MyIsam engine.

See an example here: [How do I use on delete cascade in mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/511361/how-do-i-use-on-delete-cascade-in-mysql)

Comment: Oh yes.. CONSTRAINTS... I vaguely remember something about this from university, that might be even better. I'll go read the docs. However I checked the company's database and some tables use innoDB while others MyIsam and I don't know why, don't know if I can change this without repercussions

Comment: Ok, I just read that for intense-reading capabilities, MyISAM is better and our database currently uses adjacency tree view so on a large page view with recursive loading of all the rows, there can be 1000 requests. The left and right method should have been used instead, but it's an old database so it's too late. I will definitely upvote your answer and use that in every table in the future however, thanks a million!