# Make db remove entry in different table when removing entry in one table

Tags: mysql

I have two tables,
t1:

> id,field

t2:

```
id,field,t1_id
```

t1 and t2 are connected via t1_id

Can I make the db remove the t2 entry automatically when I remove the t1 entry?

Comment: If you can drop and create them... http://stackoverflow.com/a/511390/2592994

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're running at least MySQL 5, how about:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER t1_AD AFTER DELETE ON t1 FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM t2 WHERE t1_id=OLD.id;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

(Caveat emptor: not at my workstation, have not tested!)

Comment: What is OLD.id? Are you sure it references to the "old" t1 row that is not existing anymore? Do I run this once? If I want to, how do I make it inactive?

Comment: Per MySQL docs, [OLD refers to a column of an existing row before it is deleted](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-trigger.html). Yes, you run this once. After you run this, the database will run the code between BEGIN and END every time a row in t1 is deleted. If you want to make it inactive, you can use a session variable and an IF test around the DELETE.

Comment: `DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS t1_AD`